# Not able to perform Update Operation on Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am making todo application and i am having problem doing the update operation

views.py

```
def update(request, task_id):
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST or None, instance=task)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'update.html', {'task': task})
```

forms.py

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
path('update/<int:task_id>', views.update, name='update'),
```

update.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% if task %}
<form  class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="task"  value="{{task.text}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="completed" value="{{task.completed}}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 ">Edit Task</button>

</form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock  %}
```

I am able to get the Value of the selected item in textbox but when i edit it and press Edit Task Nothing happens .

Comment: Is there a reason why you do nut use the `ModelForm` to render the form?

Answer (score 0):

```
# The url name is update, so your action submit should go to 'update'

<form action="{% url 'update' task_id=task.pk %}" method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    …
</form>
```